# reduce power consumption on this audio mixer

Tags: mixer

I'm wondering if you can reduce the mA consumed by this discrete audio mixer (on both +12V and -6V) by changing the resistors values, but keeping the same functionality (same gain, same asymmetrical clipping levels).

Also, as second question, is it possible to power this from +10V instead of +12V, keeping again the clipping levels unaltered? I guess not, since it would clip earlier, but what if you use -8V instead of -6V to balance that?

[image]

Comment: Get hold of a free sim like LTSpice and simulate it. Then try various things out until you give up and go for an op-amp solution or find a situation you like.

Comment: What andy says, plus crosstalk, plus it would be really useful for you to understand what this circuit does instead of getting someone else to modify it for you without understanding what they did

Comment: What is mentioned above but also **why ?** Why would you need to reduce the current consumption, what are you hoping to gain with that ? Most of the current is used as it flows through the PNP diffpair. I see no reason why you could not **halve** the current consumption of this circuit but I see no reason **why** that would be needed. Note that doing this will increase impedance levels and thus increase noise and/or decrease bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, but at the expense of noise.